# files in C++ and strings

Tags: c++, string, file, ifstream

i have learned basic C but i have to write a code in C++ so i am facing difficulty.there is a code

```
ifstream file(filename.c_str()); 
if (! file.is_open())
{ return -1; }
```

as much i have googled about string and then file handling in C++ ifstream is a class in C++ and it needs an object to access this class functions and variables and c_str() is a function which is being used to return a C kind of char array. but i am unable to understand that where the object is in this case? is file is an object or it is  function? and on the second line it  is calling a function is_open which seams to return a true or false but why we are calling it here before even opening the file?

Comment: I think you should probably go and do a C++ tutorial or something. This is all pretty basic stuff, and if you have to ask it here you are going to be back here a lot for all the other C++ things you'll be having trouble with...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

filename i'm presuming is a std::string which is a class that has a function c_str
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

file is using ifstream, a class which is being constructed with whatever code is in the (const char*) constructor function.
The class constructor function from ifstream opens the file on class construction so you can check to see if it succeeded.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/